# More than 1 reducer per bucket

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table that is bucketed with 1024 buckets. Max reducer limit set is 1024 and usually rule of thumb is 1 reducer per bucket. Now I want to increase # of reducers for faster performance and I want to know if I can set more than one reducer per bucket. If I can do that, then how does it affect the performance ?

Answer (score -1):

You should use

set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;

The number of reducers must equal the number of buckets. This is
described in the language manual.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables

Comment: The document does not clearly say that we cannot use more than 1 reducer per cluster/bucket. Although, it is can strongly understood that we must use 1 reducer per bucket. What I wanted to know was that if there is a setting that would actually distribute a cluster of keys to to multiple reducers